# How to generate bearer token when clicking on the link in email

Tags: java, azure, email, authentication

I want to generate bearer token when someone clicked on the email link, this token contains the identity of the person who clicked on the email link and if person forwarded the email to other person then bearer token should contain identity of forwarded person when he click on the email link(purpose of including identity here is validation of person at server side).

Email link contains service call when clicked it will call service and validate bearer token.

[Approve](http://example.com/verify?c=b53kl23d0ko234r5kok32490kdjk2uise)

Appreciate any comments here

Comment: Not sure if its possible "if person forwarded the email to other person then bearer token should generate as per person who received am email"

Comment: You can generate bearer token and keep claim information (user identity) with a token. Where is the issue?

Comment: @PankajRawat - How we can do this, can you suggest and add code snippet as an example? i am trying to click link from the email body and want to generate token when clicked upon.

Answer (score 0):

I'm generating token after the user verifies OTP. In your case, you don't need to verify anything.

**API Method**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginFunction(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "Account/Login")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        var accountDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccountDto>(requestBody);
        log.LogInformation($"ValidateOTP for phoneNumber {accountDto.PhoneNumber}");

        var isUserValid = await this.accountService.ValidateOTP(accountDto.PhoneNumber, accountDto.OTP);
        if (isUserValid)
        {
            return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(BuildToken(accountDto));
        }
        return (ActionResult)new NotFoundObjectResult("Invalid OTP");
    }

private UserToken BuildToken(AccountDto accountDto)
    {
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, accountDto.PhoneNumber)
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("LKM3LKM344NKSFN4KJ345N43KJN4KJFNK")); //read from config
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        // Expiration time
        var expiration = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1);

        JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
           issuer: AppConstraint.TokenIssuer,
           audience: AppConstraint.Audience,
           claims: claims,
           expires: expiration,
           signingCredentials: creds);

        return new UserToken()
        {
            Token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token),
            Expiration = expiration
        };
    }
```

Once you will get token you can store that token to the user's browser and send with each request.

**Custom Authorize Attribute Using MrAdvice Aspect**

```
public class AuthorizedAttribute : Attribute, IMethodAsyncAdvice
{
    public async Task Advise(MethodAsyncAdviceContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest)context.Arguments[0];
                var tokenString = request.Headers[AppConstraint.Authorization].ToString().Split(' ')[1];
                JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(tokenString);
                if (token.ValidTo <= DateTime.Now)
                {
                    throw new SecurityTokenExpiredException("Token has expired");
                }
                var claimPrincipal = GetIdentityFromToken(tokenString);
                request.HttpContext.User = claimPrincipal;
            }
            catch
            {
                context.ReturnValue = Task.FromResult<IActionResult>((ActionResult)new UnauthorizedResult());
                return;
            }
            await context.ProceedAsync(); // this calls the original method
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    private ClaimsPrincipal GetIdentityFromToken(string token)
    {
        var tokenParams = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            RequireSignedTokens = true,
            ValidAudience = AppConstraint.Audience,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidIssuer = AppConstraint.TokenIssuer,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("LKM3LKM344NKSFN4KJ345N43KJN4KJFNK"))
        };
        var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var result = handler.ValidateToken(token, tokenParams, out _);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Hope this will help to generate and verify your own token.

Comment: Please correct me if i am wrong there will be a button inside email body and this will be treated as hyperlilnk and in that link i have hardcoded some url. When person clicked on the link will be redirected to some url or call service. Now my question is when person who is clicking on the email hyperlink how we can generate token on the fly and passed with this hardcoded url?

Comment: When person clicked on the link will be redirected to some url or call service (that service will take querystring as input parameters and validation that parameter is correct then your service will generate token.

Comment: Once service will generate token, you can redirect user with token in desire page.